# Android. Do some action in parent activity, when the child activity is finished

Tags: android

For example, I have the main activity. Where I call:

```
Intent callchild = new Intent(this, childActivity.class);
startActivity(callchild);
```

And then I want to do something in the main activity when child finished.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`. when the childActivity finished the `onActivityResult()` of parent will invoke.

Note:  You must override the `onActivityResult()` of your parent Activity.

You can also set some hints according to the operations performed in the Child Activity by `setResult()` and this should be done before the ChildActivity call the `finish()` or `onDestroy()`

**Example**

From ParentActivity

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2  
            }  
        });
```

in Child Activity

```
                    Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                    setResult(2,intent);  
                    finish();//finishing activity
```

in ParentActivity

```
 // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
    @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                            textView1.setText(message);  
                         }  
     }
```

Comment: Oh thanks, It means that, if I do startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_INT_CONST); and than check in onActivityResult the requestCode == SOME_INT_CONST, it will work?

Comment: @naseermohamad (y)